# How do I pass the contents of an Entry box to a Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry box and when I enter some text into it and click a button the text should appear in the label.

I have written the following but I am unable to bind the contents of the entry box to the label.

```py
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()


e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
def get_me():
    e.get()
    print e.get()
    #e.delete(0, END)

bn = Button(root, text = "Click me", command = get_me)
bn.pack()

la = Label(root, font = "verdana 15 italic  bold", width = 20, bg = "BLUE", fg = "RED", text = get_me)
la.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter widget parameters can be modified with a dictionary like syntax, after they are
instantiated. In the case of text, the property to be changed is "text" -

So, just add this line to your button callback on your example:

```
la["text"] = e.get()
```

On a larger program, be sure to manage better variable names, and which variables are global, and so on. The advice is to bundle all your Tkinter widgets as members of a class, so that they don't rely on global variables to access each other.

Comment: you can also use the `configure` method to achieve the same results: `la.configure(text="text")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change Tkinter label's text, but you can use this:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
def get_me():
    v.set(e.get())

bn = Button(root, text = "Click me", command=get_me)
bn.pack()

v = StringVar()
# we are creating a StringVar, assigning it to our label, and then change our StringVar
la = Label(root, font = "verdana 15 italic  bold", 
              width = 20, bg = "BLUE", fg = "RED", textvariable=v)
la.pack()

mainloop()
```

For more detailed info: [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)

Comment: @sinan: yes, you can change the label's text. `la.configure(text='my new text')`